# How to integration test database view in a spring boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, view, spring-data-jpa

I have a table and view and created a corresponding JPA for these. I want to both table and view.

```
 -- account table
 CREATE TABLE account(
      user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
      username VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
      password VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
      email VARCHAR (355) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
      created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
      last_login TIMESTAMP
   );
-- account view
create view account_view as
        select user_id, email, last_login from account;
```

I added an integration test. It works fine for the table, however, the view does not have any data.

**How can I make sure that when a row is inserted in the base table, the view also gets updated in integration test?** I maybe missing some configuration. How do we add the view definition during integration test?

```
@DataJpaTest
public class AccountRepositoryIntegTest {

    @Autowired
    AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired
    AccountViewRepository accountViewRepository;

    @Test
    public void testFindByUserid(){
        Account account = Account.builder()
                .email("abc@gmail.com")
                .username("abc")
                .password("abc")
                .createdOn(new Date())
                .lastLogin(new Date())
                .build();
        Account persistedAccount = accountRepository.save(account);

        Account fetchedAccount = accountRepository.getOne(persistedAccount.getUserId());
        List<AccountView> accountViews = accountViewRepository.findAll();
        assertThat("view has data", accountViews.size(), is(Matchers.greaterThan(0)));
        assertThat(fetchedAccount.getUserId(), is(equalTo(persistedAccount.getUserId())));

    }
}
```

Comment: Not sufficient info for any conclusion. Can you also post AccountView and AccoutViewRepository?

Comment: Does it work if you use `saveAndFlush()` instead? BTW the last assertion cannot ever be false (also, you might not realize that, but `persistedAccount` and `fetchedAccount` point to the exact same object, any assertion comparing them is necessarily true)

Comment: The view is treated as a normal table from the jpa point of view. So You need to create a entity refers to the view and the repository and actually it should work by default

Answer (score 1):

As @marek.kapowicki said, the view is treated as table in JPA. This point helped me solving the problem.

When the application is running, the view data is populated by the database server. Therefore, the repository of the view is trying a select query, it gets the data.

However, during integration test, the tables are created as per the definition of the entity. The view will also be created as a table without the view definition. So, whenever you save data in the parent table, the view will not be updated.

Two ways to solve this:

1. create all the tables using sql scripts before running the integration tests. That way you can define the view and this script will be used to setup the database.
2. Create a custom entity and repository for the view that will be used only for testing. Create a custom class to process repository actions on the parent table and whenever there is an DML changes in the parent table, make sure to update the view entity according to view definition. That way, parent and view table will be in sync.

I went ahead with the second approach and it worked for me. I did not try the first approach, but it should work.